# adding jQuery click events to dynamically added content

Tags: jquery

I have a table with multiple rows and columns populated by php and mySQL. For some of the td's I'm adding jQuery click-events in the document.ready function to let the user change the content.

But I also have an option for adding rows to the table and populating them manually. But since the rows I'm adding aren't there on the document ready, they won't get the click event handler appended, and so I'm not able to click them to get input boxes.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="clickable">Some info</td>
    <td class="clickable">Some more info</td>
    <td>Unchangable info</td>
  </tr>
  ... more similar rows ...
</table>
```

and then the jQuery

```
$("tr.clickable").click(function() {
   //add input fields
}

$("span#addNewRow").click(function() {
   $("table").append('<tr><td class="clickable"></td> ... </tr>')
}
```

Comment: Great question. Fit my problem almost exactly!

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You want to use [live events](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live), which were introduced in 1.3.

```
$("tr.clickable").live("click", function() {
   //add input fields
});

$("span#addNewRow").live("click", function() {
   $("table").append('<tr><td class="clickable"></td> ... </tr>')
});
```

UPDATE: Note that as of jQuery 1.7, `live()` is deprecated. Use `on()` instead. And in some cases, `delegate()` may be a better choice. See the comments below.

Example of how to use [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("table").on("click", "tr.clickable", function() {
   //add input fields
});
```

Comment: I expect this was the best answer back in '09, but for anyone stumbling across this in more recent times, avoid using live. Use delegate() instead, as answered by Tauseef below. See http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/ for details

Comment: Excellent, just what i needed. It adds event handlers even for newly added DOM elements. Im not sure how it looks regarding to performance but it works :)

Comment: Note that `live()` is now deprecated, but [trivial to replace](http://api.jquery.com/live/) with `on()`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use .delegate() function which attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements.

Comment: although you're unlikely to get an accept 3 years down the road, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) event handler.  It doesn't handle all events, but it does handle the click event.  The handler will be bound to all current and future elements that match the selector.

```
$('tr.clickable').live( 'click', function() {
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add the event listeners after the elements are inserted.

If you are using JQuery you could use the jQuery library [livequery](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery) which allows you to add events to elements that are not yet in the dom so that you dont have to rebind events when you insert something new into the dom.