# How do I attach events to dynamic HTML elements with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dhtml

Suppose I have some jQuery code that attaches an event handler to all elements with class `.myclass`.

**For example:**

```
$(function(){
    $(".myclass").click( function() {
        // do something
    });
});
```

And my HTML might be as follows:

```
<a class="myclass" href="#">test1</a>
<a class="myclass" href="#">test2</a>
<a class="myclass" href="#">test3</a>
```

That works with no problem.
However, consider if the `.myclass` elements were written to the page at some future time.

**For example:**

```
<a id="anchor1" href="#">create link dynamically</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#anchor1").click( function() {
        $("#anchor1").append('<a class="myclass" href="#">test4</a>');
    });
});
</script>
```

In this case, the `test4` link is created when a user clicks on `a#anchor1`.

The `test4` link does not have the `click()` handler associated with it, even though it has `class="myclass"`.

Basically, I would like to write the `click()` handler once and have it apply to both content present at page load, and content brought in later via **AJAX / DHTML**. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Here's a detailed article on how to bind click event for dynamic element http://goo.gl/zlEbnv

Comment: A pure javascript only(vanilla js) solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27373951/1385441

Comment: Here is the answer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unk-U_LQWuA

Comment: Maybe this article will help: https://dontrepeatyourself.org/post/django-todo-app-with-ajax-and-jquery/#update-a-todo

Answer (score 1070, accepted):

I am adding a new answer to reflect changes in later jQuery releases. The .live() method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7.

From http://api.jquery.com/live/

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

For jQuery 1.7+ you can attach an event handler to a parent element using .on(), and pass the a selector combined with 'myclass' as an argument.

See http://api.jquery.com/on/

So instead of...

```
$(".myclass").click( function() {
    // do something
});
```

You can write...

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.myclass', function() {
    // do something
});
```

This will work for all a tags with 'myclass' in the body, whether already present or dynamically added later.

The body tag is used here as the example had no closer static surrounding tag, but any parent tag that exists when the .on method call occurs will work. For instance a ul tag for a list which will have dynamic elements added would look like this:

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
    alert( $(this).text() );
});
```

As long as the ul tag exists this will work (no li elements need exist yet).

Comment: This otherwise brilliant solution seems to have a problem with HTML content living in a Fancybox. I've reverted to creating the handlers for that manually. I didn't try iFrame Content yet, so the content of the fanyxbos is part of the body or in my case of the document variable.

Comment: live() is deprecated and .on() came. But it is not clear that when I write `$('selector').on('event', callback(){})` then it wont work. Need to write desired selector inside on(). `$(document).on('event', 'selector', callback(){})` or, `$('body').on('event', 'selector', callback(){})`

Comment: what about performance? is it the same as attaching events directly?

Comment: Not work when `<a>` element have `href` address that set to `http://????`

Comment: `$('body').on('each', 'myclass', function() {
    // do something
});` @Sean I tried to make something on "each" of a "class", but it doesn't work. What is wrong?

Comment: in my case, it instead assigns the event on the parent tag. I use jquery version 1.12.4. Any idea?

Comment: Excellent solution, works well when adding DOM elements via javascript which were added during `document.ready`.

Comment: @Sean and Chuck, Thanks for the answer and the editing respectively. :)

Comment: $('.yourDynamicElement').attr('onClick', 'yourFunction()'); would also work properly

Comment: As @Juan said, I am also concerned about performance, is this going to perform more evaluations than directly attatching the event to the specific element?

Answer (score 123):

Sometimes doing this **(the top-voted answer)** is not always enough:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.myclass', function() {
    // do something
});
```

This can be an issue because of the order event handlers are fired. If you find yourself doing this, but it is causing issues because of the order in which it is handled.. You can always wrap that into a function, that when called "refreshes" the listener.

For example:

```
function RefreshSomeEventListener() {
    // Remove handler from existing elements
    $("#wrapper .specific-selector").off(); 

    // Re-add event handler for all matching elements
    $("#wrapper .specific-selector").on("click", function() {
        // Handle event.
    }
}
```

Because it is a function, whenever I set up my listener this way, I typically call it on document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Other ready commands / code

    // Call our function to setup initial listening
    RefreshSomeEventListener();
});
```

Then, whenever you add some dynamically added element, call that method again:

```
function SomeMethodThatAddsElement() {
    // Some code / AJAX / whatever.. Adding element dynamically

    // Refresh our listener, so the new element is taken into account
    RefreshSomeEventListener();
}
```

Hopefully this helps!

Regards,

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't get it to work with other answers, your solution worked like a charm, however if I call RefreshSomeEventListener() after adding dynamic element, my event is triggered twice

Comment: @DKMudrechenko Likely this is because you're not fully removing the event listeners from it.

Comment: This works, and good explanation, too.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 36):

After jQuery 1.7 the preferred methods are [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

[Sean's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9331127/24970) shows an example.

### Now Deprecated:

> Use the jQuery functions [`.live()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) and [`.die()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/die).  Available in
>   jQuery 1.3.x
>
> From the docs:
>
> > To display each paragraph's text in an
> >     alert box whenever it is clicked:
> >
> > ```
> > $("p").live("click", function(){
> >   alert( $(this).text() );
> > });
> > ```
>
> Also, the [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery/livequery) plugin does this and has support for more events.

Comment: What if my selector needs to be the parent of some other element? For example:
$("p").parent(".myclass").live("click", ...
This doesn't seem to work with live().

Comment: You could try to incorporate that into a single query like $("p:has(.myclass)").live("click",...).  Note: there are some cases where live doesn't work for all events.  Check out livequery plugin for support not offered by live.

Comment: This is no longer the correct Answer. The .live() method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7.  Use `.on()` instead.  Lets get the correct answer[http://stackoverflow.com/a/9331127/363701] some upvotes.  Or @Matt - do you want to update your answer?

Answer (score 6):

If you're adding a pile of anchors to the DOM, look into event delegation instead.

Here's a simple example:

```
$('#somecontainer').click(function(e) {   
  var $target = $(e.target);   
  if ($target.hasClass("myclass")) {
    // do something
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can bind a single click event to a page for all elements, no matter if they are already on that page or if they will arrive at some future time, like that:

```
$(document).bind('click', function (e) {
   var target = $(e.target);
   if (target.is('.myclass')) {
      e.preventDefault(); // if you want to cancel the event flow
      // do something
   } else if (target.is('.myotherclass')) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // do something else
   }
});
```

Been using it for a while. Works like a charm.

In jQuery 1.7 and later, it is recommended to use `.on()` in place of bind or any other event delegation method, but `.bind()` still works.

Answer (score 3):

Binds a handler to an event (like click) for all current - and future - matched element. Can also bind custom events.

[link text](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live)

```
$(function(){
    $(".myclass").live("click", function() {
        // do something
    });
});
```

Comment: `live` is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

If your on jQuery 1.3+ then use .[live()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live)

> Binds a handler to an event (like
>   click) for all current - and future -
>   matched element. Can also bind custom
>   events.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `live()` function. See [the docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live).

For example:

```
$("#anchor1").live("click", function() {
    $("#anchor1").append('<a class="myclass" href="#">test4</a>');
});
```

Comment: live is deprecated.