# How to append <li> to another <ol> on click event using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-append

I have a dynamically generated list, Here is my HTML code

```
<ol class="pending">
  <li><a href="#" class="rendered">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="rendered">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="rendered">Three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="rendered">Four</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="rendered">Five</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="rendered">Six</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="patched"></ol>
```

When any particular link is clicked, It should moved to different list.

```
/*jslint browser: true*/ /*global  $*/ 
$(document).ready(function(){
    "use strict";
    $('.rendered').on('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("rendered patched");
        //$(this).parent().append($(this).wrap("<li></li>"));
        $(this).appendTo("ol.patched");
    });
});
```

So far the only difficulty is in having the anchor value in the <li> added to the new list as an <li>.

The result I keep getting is

```
<ol class="pending">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol> 
<ol class="moved">
  <a href="#" class="dld">One</a>
  <a href="#" class="dld">Two</a>
  <a href="#" class="dld">Three</a>
  <a href="#" class="dld">Four</a>
  <a href="#" class="dld">Five</a>
  <a href="#" class="dld">Six</a>
</ol>
```

I'm not sure what I am misunderstanding about `.append()` and `.appendTo()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding jQuery click events to dynamically added content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852450/adding-jquery-click-events-to-dynamically-added-content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select parent of anchor and append it to `ol`. JQuery [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) select parent of element.

```
$('.rendered').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("rendered patched");
    $(this).parent().appendTo("ol.patched");
});
```

```js
$('.rendered').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("rendered patched");
  $(this).parent().appendTo("ol.patched");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="pending">
  <li><a href="#" class="rendered">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="rendered">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="rendered">Three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="rendered">Four</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="rendered">Five</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="rendered">Six</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="patched"></ol>
```

Also you can write your code in one line

```
$('.rendered').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("rendered patched").parent().appendTo("ol.patched");
});
```